# При чем тут муха?

Tags: фразеология

"Любили они муху зашибить". Муху можно также убить, урезать или быть под мухой. А каково происхождение этих выражений,  насколько они распространены сейчас?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...Итак, ***муха*** или ***мушка*** — это была модная карточная игра в начале XIX
>   века. П.  А.  Вяземский писал А. И. Тургеневу 18 апреля 1828 г.:
>   «...На днях же и сам дебютировал в муху (игра карточная в моде) ...»

Подробнее см.:  МУХУ ЗАШИБИТЬ, МУХУ ЗАДАВИТЬ, МУХУ РАЗДАВИТЬ, МУХУ УБИТЬ, С МУХОЙ, ПОД МУХОЙ - [В. В. ВИНОГРАДОВ. ИСТОРИЯ СЛОВ](http://wordhist.narod.ru/muhu_zashibit.html).

---

> ...[Раньше была популярна игра в Мушку](http://dslov.ru/fslov/f421.htm) (кстати, эта игра еще существует
>   и сейчас). Выпивая за удачу, говорили - "с мушкой". Так муха стала
>   связана с выпивкой.
>
> Но, на наш взгляд, наиболее вероятное объяснение - до 20 века были
>   популярны стаканы с изображением мух на стекле. Поэтому про человека,
>   который выпил много стаканов алкоголя, и говорили: "муху зашиб", "под
>   мухой".

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, очень интересная и познавательная статья.

Comment: Мне самой было интересно. Вторая цитата - немножко самодеятельность, а первая - целое диссертейшн на тему.

Comment: Ерунда. Не все, что можно нагуглить правильный ответ. Игра в муху - была такая, но к выражению "под мухой" одна никак не относилась, за уши притянуто.

Answer (score -1):

Вот, найдено в сети, нечто под чем я готоап подписаться.

> На Руси водку пили всегда - национальная, так сказать, традиция. Пили
>   все: начиная с царей да князей и заканчивая простым людом.
>
> Пили ее тоже по-русски - чарками, то есть примерно по 150 граммов за
>   раз. Десять чарок были равны стопе. В XVIII веке стопу заменил штоф
>   (1,23 литра). От полуштофа произошли современные пол-литра. Был в ходу
>   и небольшой стаканчик со смешным названием «муха». От него и пошло
>   выражение «быть под мухой».

Что же касается мнения Galina Avanesova, то сдается мне, что это довольно вольная интерпретация текста Виноградова (из "Истории слов"), посвященного идиоматике слова "муха" вообще, без привязки конкретно к хмельному значению. К сожалению, не могу найти в сети, а мой бумажный экземпляр, увы, кто-то увел...

Цитирую по найденному в сети отрывку.

> <...>МУХУ ЗАДАВИТЬ, МУХУ РАЗДАВИТЬ, МУХУ УБИТЬ, С МУХОЙ, ПОД МУХОЙ
>   Выражения муху убить, муху зашибить, муху задавить, муху раздавить
>   являются своеобразными идиоматическими синонимами<...>
>
> <...>Таким образом, внутренний анализ выражения убить муху приводит к
>   выводу, что оно возникло в игрецком картежно-профессиональном жаргоне,
>   по-видимому, еще в ту пору, когда он был тесно связан с социальными
>   диалектами военной среды (преимущественно дворянско-помещичьей и
>   дворовой окраски)<...>
>
> <...>На том историческом фоне, который здесь вырисовывается, вся соль
>   экспрессивно-образных словесных воплощений выпивки, пьянства
>   сосредоточивается в слове муха. Это обстоятельство отражается и в тех
>   деформациях, которым подвергаются связанные с ним фразеологизмы. <...>
>
> <...>Именно в результате таких процессов возникли детерминативные
>   сочетания слов с мухой, под мухой.<...>
>
> <...>Позднее на основе аналогических приравнений к выражениям под
>   хмельком и т. п. возникло сочетание слов под мухой, например, у К.
>   Паустовского в «Колхиде»: «Парень, должно быть, был под мухой, -
>   добавил Чоп от себя. - Выпил поллитровочки водки»<...>

А, открылась ссылка.  Ну так и есть. Самая содержательная, посвященная конкретно выражению "под мухой", часть виноградовского текста у Галины отсутствует.